# Discrete Mathematics Stamp problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am very confused on how to solve.

Use the Principle of Mathematical Induction to prove that every amount of
postage of 18 cents or more can be formed using just 4-cent and 7-cent stamps.

Comment: Do you have to use induction to prove?

Comment: Yes, this must be proved by Mathematical Induction.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [some](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181657/how-to-prove-what-amounts-of-postage-can-be-formed-with-normal-mathematical-indu?rq=1) [of](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178624/how-to-determine-which-amounts-of-postage-can-be-formed-by-using-just-4-cent-and?rq=1) [these](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043891/prove-that-every-amount-of-postage-of-12-cents-or-more-can-be-formed-using-just?rq=1) [similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565659/solve-discrete-math-problem-using-abstract-algebra-postage-problem?rq=1) questions?

Answer (score 4):

You can create the first four in the following way:

$18 = 2\cdot 7 + 1 \cdot 4$

$19 = 1\cdot 7 + 3 \cdot 4$

$20 = 0\cdot 7 + 5 \cdot 4$

$21 = 3\cdot 7 + 0 \cdot 4$

Now assume that you can create all values $18, 19 , 20, 21, \cdots , k$.

Then you can create $k+1$ as $(k-3) + 1\cdot 4$. Hence, we are done by induction.